# Move HDD from one laptop to another and retain active logins?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, browser, data-recovery, cookies

My laptop recently died, and I plan to move the hard drive from the dead laptop to a new laptop. Will I (/can I/when can I) retain my active logins in Firefox or Chrome if I do that?

(I am logged into a site using an account for which I forgot my password. The dead laptop is running Windows 10.)

Comment: Unless you installed Windows Retail on your old laptop, it will be Windows OEM and you cannot even move it to a new computer. You will have to set up your logins again.

Comment: Thanks @John. If you post this as the answer, I will accept it!

Comment: Thanks I did post an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving a hard drive with operating system only works for a installed Windows Retail operating system on your old laptop.

Otherwise it will be Windows OEM and you cannot move it to a new computer as the Microsoft requirements do not allow this and it likely will not activate.

You will have to set up your logins again on the new laptop and new Windows operating system.

That is how OEM works.

Comment: It is not certain that the installation of Windows on the hard drive will even work on a different laptop. if the hardware is absolutely identical, it would probably work OK but the hardware would have different serial number IDs (motherboard chipset, CPU, etc) and an OEM Windows would become unlicensed and not activated.

Comment: Very old operating systems sometimes moved but most newer ones will complain at least in terms of OEM. If Retail, drivers could be an issue as you note in your post.

Answer (score 1):

This refers to only chrome and firefox.

Both have folders in the hidden APPDATA folder.

If you copy them over correctly you can restore chrome and firefox bookmarks and etc.